# Is it normal that the Abus Bordo folding lock rattles?

Tags: noise, lock

I have the latest Abus Bordo Granite X-Plus 6500 folding lock:

[image: Abus Bordo lock]

It is cased inside a rubberized pouch that attaches to one of the bottle-cage locations:

[image: Pouch on bike]

Very convenient, but sadly, it **rattles while riding on an uneven surface**, which can get quite annoying, and does not make for a smooth ride.

Firstly, is that normal, or is something wrong? (Has one of the bolts come looser than it should be?)

Secondly, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Mine is on its way. I hope mine doesn't rattle! (But I haven't heard of it rattling before, either.)

Comment: @Matt, keep me updated! Maybe I need to exchange mine... (could signify a weakness)

Comment: Mine seems to rattle less after moving it from a angled mount to a horizontal position.

Comment: Unrelated - these locks have been proven to open to an open-mouthed nut splitter like this   https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8ukAAOSwr7ZW8eNN/s-l500.jpg     as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zs8uyPsDaw0

Answer (score 7):

This is a late answer I know, but I've found a solution to the rattling problem. I've had an Abus 6500 for nearly 3 years now and the rattling always annoyed me. I used to wrap a kind of nylon strap between the lock as I folded it and that partly solved it, although most of the rattle was coming from the joints themselves. It was only just today when I thought of this: I sprayed some chain oil, the type that comes in a spray can, into the joints, between the bars. As you may know, this oil is very liquid when sprayed but soon solidifies as the solvent evaporates. This allows it to get right into the joint and GREATLY reduce rattle. There is inevitably some that runs onto the parts you need to touch so a bit of cleaning up afterwards is necessary but the result for me is just astounding. I just wish I'd thought of it 3 years ago!

Comment: Great suggestion. Any idea if this affects the security of the lock?

Comment: It shouldn't, you're spaying a lubricant designed for steel onto steel. If it weakens the plastic that's cosmetic, but it shouldn't do that because who would build a bike lock that's vulnerable to bicycle chain oil? "caution: do not use near chain"??

Comment: I have a similar lock and an identical problem. Will give this a try!

Answer (score 4):

I complained about the noise to ABUS and they told me they will substitute them, asap. It's a design/factory problem.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting, I contacted them, and they offered no such thing. What did you say to them and how?

Answer (score 3):

I made judicious use of little 10mm o-rings on my Abus. No more rattles.

Comment: Welcome to SE - that's a good idea.  Can you please look at expanding your answer with more info?  Perhaps a photo of the lock, and maybe some comments on how its wearing.  Does it rattle at all any more ?

Answer (score 2):

Mine just arrived and I mounted it to my frame just like the picture above (though, my lock looks slightly different... still the x-plus.)

It rattles just like every other attachment on my bicycle (including the chain when it's not taut). I think it's quite normal... it *does* have movable parts, after all.

I bet the rattling can be dampened by using a small felt pad wrapped around it or between the links, but I haven't tried this. Personally, the rattling doesn't bother me because I'm so focused on the ride and just being out on the bike.

If you carry a bag, putting it in there would probably stifle much of the rattle. Using a messenger bag would lower the load's center of gravity.

As for a bolt coming loose, if you can't fit anything of much strength (more than tweezers?) between the bolt and the link, it's probably not too loose. I can't see these links just falling apart in my own lock anyway... so unless you notice a significant separation, I bet the lock is fine.

Incidentally, did you mount it using the velcro straps or by screwing it into the frame using the mounting points? If you use the screws, it's possible that the lock is bumping against them causing the rattle, but then again, shaking the lock in my hand without other metal also produces a slight rattle. If you try using the velcro to mount instead, perhaps the rattle will be reduced?

Comment: Does yours look more [like this](http://www.londoncyclist.co.uk/abus-bordo-granit-xplus-lock/)? I used the velcro first, and then screws (velcro was annoying as it wasn't as strong, and the strap would rub against my leg)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. Mine is screwed in as well (but I was impressed with the quality of the velcro straps). My hope is that a thief here in the US will be deterred because Abus locks aren't common around here and they aren't familiar. I guess it's worth the rattle...

Comment: Sounds like a plan. While this could just be anecdotal evidence, it's unfortunate to hear that the newer version of the lock (likely not actually any more secure, just more padding) rattles *more*

Comment: It may not actually rattle more. I ride different roads than you do or may just notice it less. Anyway, I'm sure you'll find a nice solution with time that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for the lock itself to rattle if you shake it, especially when it's folded up. That said, I have an earlier model of the lock, and mine doesn't rattle audibly when it's in the rubber carrying case: the case is tight enough to stop it rattling. It's possible that Abus have made the case a little looser in newer versions, to make it easier to insert and remove the lock.

Is it definitely the lock rattling, rather than the case itself? The case has a metal plate that the bottle-cage bolts sit against, and if one of them is slightly loose, the weight of the lock would cause the case to rattle. Try tightening the screws. Alternatively, it could be that when inside the case, the lock is in contact with a bike component (such as the mounting for the front derailleur) and that's causing the rattle. If you have a second mounting point, it might be worth trying that to avoid wear to the fouled component.

Answer (score 1):

All Bordo locks rattle no matter what in the water bottle mount, what I do is put it in my under seat saddlebag and put my wallet and cell phone ontop of it.  It won't rattle that way.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the questions, but thanks for your effort