# How to fix folding lock holder

Tags: repair, lock, cargo, storage

I've got an [ABUS Bordo Lite](http://www.abus.com/eng/Mobile-Security/Bike-Safety-and-Security/Locks/Folding-locks/Bordo-Lite-6050) folding lock and the holder it came with which attaches to the bicycle's frame using two thin metal strips and/or two Velcro straps is now broken:
[image: Folding lock holder with broken strap]

As you can see, the soft plastic strap keeping the lock securely in the "holster" tore. Although the lock itself doesn't fall out when keeping the holster open as depicted, it does [rattle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/16156/8685) around a bit and, more importantly, the strap itself is incredibly annoying because it moves around and sometimes tickles my sensitive, powerful-yet-dainty high-performance calves (no, I don't [shave them](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#33)).

### Attempted solutions

- **Rubber band:** I had tried wrapping a rubber band around the "inside" loop on the upper part of the strap and then wrapping the rubber band around the nub (what is it called?) on the holster itself, but the rubber band becomes more and more slack with time and then itself becomes loose.
- **Electrical tape:** I tried wrapping electrical tape around the broken loop in order to try to hold the loop together, but it couldn't withstand the stress of the loop being closed around the "nub" on the holster.
- **Superglue:** I tried supergluing the broken loop back together by letting the glue "set" inside a wrapping of electrical tape, but it didn't hold.
- **Kill it with fire:** Since some plastics are re-formable, I had tried melting the broken loop with a lighter and then "re-forming" it by holding it together with electrical tape until it re-set. That didn't work at all and simply made it look uglier than before.

Comment: You may try contacting them, probably won't help but you never know, assuming you haven't yet. Abus is pretty proud of their stuff and they may be willing to replace the holster for you. Just a thought

Comment: Yeah. Chances are they will send you a new one for some nominal fee

Comment: @NateWengert: I finally got around to contacting ABUS and it seems they will in fact replace it for me; You should make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it!

Comment: @errantlinguist one has been added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't taken the time to yet, you should contact Abus, they are generally pretty proud of their products and stand by their workmanship. I would not be surprised if they replaced the holster all together for you. This is where i would start before trying to repair it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest cutting the broken loop off and using a cable ("zip") tie through the big triangular loop.  Two cable ties chained together may help it lie flatter.  As an alternative a short loop of bungee cord would also do the trick (available from camping shops).

Thats actually nicer than most lock holders, and seems worth saving.

Edit:Picture:[image: Sketch]

Comment: I scrolled down to make the bungee cord suggestion but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same lock and the same issue. The lock holder is mounted to the seat tube on my bike, so the lock can't fall out while riding. If the plastic strap disturbs you and the lock isn't falling out while you ride, I recommend you to simply cut off the strap.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be to cut a ring of aluminium, and pop-rivet it around the hole.  Roughen the plastic, and use some epoxy between them, then apply pop rivets so the flattest side is against the lock.  You might want to use a peening hammer to flatten and round-off the side where your fingers are.  Also watch out for making it too thick.

Contact the supplier and see if a replacement is available - looks like a good holder, just lacking in the design department.  Maybe a later model has more meat in that area.